# how to calculate oil stock with conversion from drums to liters with vba excel

Tags: excel

please help with the vba excel code for this case: I have 10 drums of oil stock, 1 drum we consider as 208 liters, when a customer buys 1 liter of oil, the last stock will automatically be 9 drums and 207 liters, thank you for any help

i dont have any idea to do this

Comment: Why do you need vba? this can be done with simple mathematics in cells.

Comment: @SolarMike I want to make a stock program with vba

Comment: Then consider what you need to track and how to calculate the running totals then write your code. People on here will not build it for you, but they might help you improve your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

So you can expand on this, but here is a very simple layout:

[image]

You could add a test to track stock level etc and prices as well.